# Can you store functions in variables?

Tags: methods, message, smalltalk

I am currently studying a bit of Smalltalk.

Is there a way you can store a function or method inside a variable?

For example, in Python one could say:

```
x = someobject.method
x() # calling it
```

Is this possible in Smalltalk? What about passing `something.method` itself as an argument to another method?

Comment: As Andrei clearly explained in his (excellent) answer, the possibility exists. However, unless you are doing something unusual, you would typically use _blocks_, rather than _compiled methods_ or _selectors_. The use of `perform` might indicate a poor design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a method object, by asking the class object for a method with a given name. Below `>>` is a message send to the class `Object` with the method name as a parameter.

`Object >> #asString`

This returns an instance of type `CompiledMethod`. This is an object representing a method. Like any object you can store it inside a variable.

`copyMethod := Object>>#asString.`

For example, if you open in Pharo a Playground and inspect the code above you get:

[executing code in playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Ft5.png)

You can then execute the method using the message `#valueWithReceiver:arguments:`. This needs as a parameter the receiver (self/this) and possible arguments.

```
result := copyMethod 
    valueWithReceiver: Object new arguments: #().
```

[executing the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVit6.png)

However, this is a low level way to execute a method.

I'd say more common is to the directly execute a method with a given name on an object. That can be done using `perform:` or `perform:withArguments:`. You can send this to the object with the method name as argument

```
receiver := Object new.
receiver perform: #asString.
```

The code above executes the method named `asString` on the receiver object. This is often used to pass the names of methods that we need to execute. The difference is that instances of `CompiledMethod` are immutable. If you change the code of that method a new instance is created and you can end up executing an older version of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, all you should do in Smalltalk is sending messages. You never execute a method because it is a violation of encapsulation and generally not the right level of abstraction.

When you send a message, the receiver object lookup in its class methodDictionary for associating a CompiledMethod to the message selector, if none, it then lookup in superclass methodDictionary, etc... or finally send doesNotUnderstand: message if no corresponding method were found. All this machinery is performed in the VM. It's not the programmer job.

When you want to send a message which is a variable, you can use `perform:` `perform:with:` `perform:withArgument:` as explained by @andrei-chis.

```
selector:= #(printString storeString asString) at: index.
^self perform: selector
```

For giving access to low level machinery, we can directly invoke the method by sending the message `valueWithReceiver:arguments:`, but I strongly advise not to use it... Such access to low level machinery is dedicated to debugging support and as I said not the right level of abstraction - unless you are trying to implement another language above the Smalltalk VM and seeking for such low level constructs.

If you pass over this warning, then it is your responsibility to provide an instance of the correct class as receiver (or if you want to hack, at least provide an object with enough room allocated for instance variables etc...). The least failure in doing so, and you can corrupt object memory and have the VM crashing sooner or later, and loose some of your work if you had time to save a corrupted image before the fatal crash...

So in one word, think in term of sending messages to objects and not invoking method; let objects decide by themselves which method to execute, that's not our business, Smalltalk is messages all the way down.